# Cannot call a method on closed teradata jdbc connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, teradata

In my spring boot project I am losing sometimes the connection to the teradata database. I would like to know how I can tell spring to close and open the connection again.

I see after several days of runtime exceptions like

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.10.00.03] [Error 1095] [SQLState HY000] Cannot call a method on closed connection
>       at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:95) ~[terajdbc4-16.10.00.03.jar!/:16.10.00.03]
>       at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:65) ~[terajdbc4-16.10.00.03.jar!/:16.10.00.03]
>       at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareStatement(TDSession.java:1323) ~[terajdbc4-16.10.00.03.jar!/:16.10.00.03]
>       at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareStatement(TDSession.java:1375) ~[terajdbc4-16.10.00.03.jar!/:16.10.00.03]
>       at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareStatement(TDSession.java:1361) ~[terajdbc4-16.10.00.03.jar!/:16.10.00.03]
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar!/:na]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar!/:na]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:75) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar!/:na]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar!/:na]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar!/:na]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1521) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:627) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
>       ... 25 common frames omitted

When trying to access the database.

I am using an autowired JdbcTemplate when accessing the database. I can catch the exception, but I do not know how to tell spring to kill and reconnect to the database.

I am using the following dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teradata.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>terajdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>16.10.00.03</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teradata.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>tdgssconfig</artifactId>
        <version>16.10.00.03</version>
    </dependency>
```

After searching stackoverflow, I found examples how to add reconnection configs for different databases, but not for teradata. Can I use similar configs?

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.sql.Connection conn;
java.sql.Statement stmt;

try {
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.executeQuery("SELECT USER");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // ... open connection here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how should I get the connection that is spring-data-jpa using?